# extract attribute (i.e. font) from ggplot2 theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot2 theme that is used for a whole shiny app. There is however one plot that is not a ggplot (so I can't directly use that theme).

Is there a way to extract the font and other attributes from the (ggplot2) theme?

Edit:
Let's say I have a theme `customtheme` that is defined somewhere and used in many places. Now I want to extract the font, fontsize, etc so I can use them somewhere where I can't use ggplot2 themes.

Comment: You want to extract the theme from a plot that isn't a `ggplot`? That doesn't really make sense. Could you perhaps edit your question to show a reproducible example?

Comment: And you may want to have a look at [thematic](https://rstudio.github.io/thematic/index.html)

Comment: @AllanCameron No, I have a ggplot theme from which I want to extract attributes like the font so I can use them in something that is not ggplot.

Comment: Try `customtheme$text` - this will give you a list with members such as `family` and `face`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you! :) That's excactly what I was looking for!